Selenium Python Script Failing for unknown reason
Its pretty self explanatory as to what the script does but to summarize, it opens youtube and types "hello" into the search bar then presses enter. The issue is that it opens youtube but doesn't type hello or press enter.
heres the code
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Set up the driver for Chrome
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Replace the URL below with the webpage you want to interact with
driver.get('https://youtube.com')

# Give the page some time to load
time.sleep(2)

# Locate the search bar using its name attribute
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.ID('search'))

# Words to type
words = ['hello']

# Type each word and press ENTER
for word in words:
    search_bar.clear()  # Clear the search bar before typing
    search_bar.send_keys(word)
    search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)  # Wait a bit between each word

# Close the browser when done
driver.quit()


I've tried switching it to Google.com instead of youtube and i've checked the element ID for the search but I think its all correct

It's not failing for an unknown reason. When you run the script, it gives you an error message. That would have been helpful in your question. The relevant bit of the error message is
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.ID('search'))
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable


The first issue is that your locator syntax is not python, it's some mix of python and Java or C#. The syntax should be
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'search')


The second issue is that the ID you are using is not unique on the page. There's actually 3 elements that have that ID and the one you are looking for is the second which means we need to find a new locator that uniquely identifies the element we want. The CSS selector below works
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ytd-searchbox #search")



Using these two suggestions and a little more cleanup, the working script is below
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Set up the driver for Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Replace the URL below with the webpage you want to interact with
driver.get('https://youtube.com')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Words to type
words = ['hello', 'selenium']

# Type each word and press ENTER
for word in words:
    # Locate the search bar
    search_bar = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ytd-searchbox #search")))
    search_bar.clear()  # Clear the search bar before typing
    search_bar.send_keys(word)
    search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)  # Wait a bit between each word

# Close the browser when done
driver.quit()

